# Docker-compose not adding dependent container to /etc/hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose

A dependent host name is not being added and that is needed for my web app to connect to my other service (postgres)

Here is an example of my `/etc/hosts`

```
root@bdd6f863aced:/myapp# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.21.0.3      bdd6f863aced
```

The last entry is the current container, not the postgres container

Steps to repeat:

```
git clone repo git@github.com:tushartuteja/rails-docker-compose-example.git
cd rails-docker-compose-example
docker-compose up --build
docker ps # get the id for the web container
docker exec -it {host-container id} /bin/bash
rake db:create
cat /etc/hosts
```

When you attempt to do a create you will get this error message:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
```

docer-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
```

Additional info here:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7442

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `links` entry, this is will help you

Comment: I have and did again. The result is the same.

Comment: So, as i can see on github issues your docker-compose file looks strange. Could you please post it here in question?

Comment: I added my docker-compose.yaml @Vasiliy Novikov

Comment: First of all - you database container not started (as I can reproduce) ```Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified```, you can see it by docker-compose logs ```docker-compose logs db```.
Next one - you can enter to bash console easily with using docker-compose instead plain docker ```docker-compose exec web bash```